# Is it possible to delete a non-new object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, new-operator

I have an object with a vector of pointers to other objects in it, something like this:

```
class Object {
    ...
    vector<Object*> objlist;
    ...
};
```

Now, Objects will be added to list in both of these ways:

```
Object obj;
obj.objlist.push_back(new Object);
```

and

```
Object name;
Object* anon = &name;
obj.objlist.push_back(anon);
```

If a make a destructor that is simply

```
~Object {
    for (int i = 0; i < objlist.size(); i++) {
        delete objlist[i];
        objlist[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Will there be any adverse consequences in terms of when it tries to delete an object that was not created with new?

Comment: I know that it could be better with an iterator, but `objlist` was originally and array and I haven't got around to changing the loop.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, there will be adverse effects.

You must not `delete` an object that was not allocated with `new`. If the object was allocated on the stack, your compiler has already generated a call to its destructor at the end of its scope. This means you will call the destructor twice, with potentially very bad effects.

Besides calling the destructor twice, you will also attempt to deallocate a memory block that was *never* allocated. The `new` operator presumably puts the objects on the heap; `delete` expects to find the object in the same region the `new` operator puts them. However, your object that was not allocated with `new` lives on the stack. This will very probably crash your program (if it does not already crash after calling the destructor a second time).

You'll also get in deep trouble if your `Object` on the heap lives longer than your `Object` on the stack: you'll get a dangling reference to somewhere on the stack, and you'll get incorrect results/crash the next time you access it.

The general rule I see is that stuff that live on the stack can reference stuff that lives on the heap, but stuff on the heap should not reference stuff on the stack because of the very high chances that they'll outlive stack objects. And pointers to both should not be mixed together.

Comment: I see.  Than is there any way to ensure that when the Object is destroyed, everything in objlist that was put there with new is deleted, and nothing else?

Comment: @Keand64 There is no language feature to help you there. Once you have a pointer, you can't (without platform-dependant dark magic/unsafe operations) know if it points to somewhere on the stack or on the heap. It's a generally bad idea to mix objects that live on the stack and objects that live on the heap. Your best bet would be to use `new` for all of them.

Comment: @Keand64: What you are supposed to do is make the same code responsible for the `new` ing as for the `delete` ing. For containers, you let the container do both, by having it explicitly copy everything that's put into the container. (This also protects you against the calling code letting the pointed-at thing fall out of scope.) But **don't write your own containers anyway**; the standard library provides what you need.

Comment: Ithink this is a good answer ! But what I miss in it ,is that it's possible to take over a class's memory management (all operators new and delete),which can make it possible to call delete on every pointer. (don't think you should though)

Answer (score 6):

No, you can only `delete` what you `new`ed

```
Object* anon = &name;
```

When name goes out of scope, you will have an invalid pointer in your vector.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work - if you `delete` an object that wasn't allocated by `new` you've violated the rules or the `delete` operator.

If you need to have your vector store objects that may or may not need to be deleted, you'll need to keep track of that somehow.  One option is to use a smart pointer that keeps track of whether the pointed to object is dynamic or not. For example, `shared_ptr<>` allows you to specify a deallocator object when constructing the `shard_ptr<>` and as the docs mention:

> For example, a "no-op" deallocator is useful when returning a shared_ptr to a statically allocated object

However, you should still be careful when passing pointers to automatic variables - if the vector's lifetime is longer than the lifetime of the variable then it'll be refering to garbage at some point.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually asking is whether it's safe to delete an object not allocated via `new` through the `delete` operator, and if so, why?

Unfortunately, this is obfuscated by some other problems in your code. As mentioned, when *name* goes out of scope, you're going to end up with an invalid pointer.

See [zneak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355468/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-non-new-object-c/4355485#4355485) for why your original question doesn't result in a safe operation, and why the scope for *name* actually matters.