# Allocating an array of zeros

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, zero

I'm trying to create a single 5 in the fifth instance of an array of twenty zeros. I did get the 5 where I wanted, but doing this has cause four additional zeros to follow raising the array count to 24. What is causing this to happen? I've tried everything, and changing it gives me junk values.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class PartFilledArray
{
public:
    PartFilledArray(); //create instance
    PartFilledArray(int array_size); //declares the sizes of arrays being added

    //Overloading Assignment Operator
    PartFilledArray operator = (const PartFilledArray& other)
    {
        if(this == &other) return *this; // handling of self assignment
        delete[] a; // freeing previously used memory
        double a[20];
        int _size = number_used; memcpy(a, other.a, sizeof(int) * _size);
        return *this;
    }
        void add_value(double new_entry); 
        void print_array(); 

    //copy constructor
    PartFilledArray::PartFilledArray( const PartFilledArray& other )
    {
        max_number = other.max_number;
        number_used = other.number_used;
    }

    //deconstructor
    ~PartFilledArray()
    {
        //delete [] a; 
    } 

protected:
    double a[20]; //declares first array 
    int max_number;
    int number_used;
};
#endif  

//Precondition: an array of 20 elements must all equal 0. 
//Postcondition: This fifth element in the array will take the value of 5.

int main ()
{
    PartFilledArray instance(20);
    instance.print_array();

    int new_entry = 5; //declares at the fifth element
    int array_size = 20;

    instance.add_value(new_entry);
    instance.print_array();

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

PartFilledArray::PartFilledArray(int array_size) : max_number(array_size), number_used(0) 
{
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        {
            a[i] = 0; // adds element in array
        }
    }

} 

void PartFilledArray::add_value(double new_entry)
{
    a[number_used] = new_entry;
    number_used = number_used + 1;
}

void PartFilledArray::print_array()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout <<  a[i] << endl; //prints the array of elements
    }
}
```

Comment: In `operator=` you are making a local object `double a[20];`. Also you can't delete an array created with `double a[20];`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Make this an answer, this might solve all of the OP's unasked questions.

Comment: For more info on what @JohnnyMopp said, See here: [SO explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355468/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-non-new-object)

Answer (score 0):

add_value() is adding an entry to the end of the array (beyond where you've allocated memory). You then increase the count of the number of elements.

This is why you array seems to grow. In fact, you are stepping beyond the memory allocated.

To accomplish what you want, you would need to change the add_value interface to look something like this:

```
void PartFilledArray::add_value(int offset, double new_entry)
{
    a[offset] = new_entry;
}
```

Of course good programming would dictate that you check the offset to make sure it isn't beyond your array.